# Laravel 4 routing for simple contact us form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I've worked with MVC's using Java but first time using Laravel. In Java I can indicate in my controller the URL and method (POST or GET) to handle. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Laravel for a contact us form that emails me when a user fills out the form.

In routes.php I have:

```
Route::controller('/contact-us', 'ContactUsController');
```

In my ContactUsController I have:

```
public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('contact-us');
}

public function postForm($data) {
    //Handle form
    return View::make('contact-us-success');
}
```

With the "getIndex()" function I can see the contact us page. However clicking "Submit" on the form (which submits to the same /contact-us URL as the GET page) gives me a "Controller method not found" error. Do I need to make the form submit to something like contact-us/store or is it possible to have the GET/POST page be the same URL? Also, I want to use my controllers to handle routes instead of putting a new line in routes.php for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `POST /contact-us` posts to the index route, create a `postIndex` method:

```
public function postIndex($data) {
    //Handle form
    return View::make('contact-us-success');
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now. That worked like a charm, thanks Joseph!